# Display countdown timer on simulator for a quiz type application

Tags: blackberry

I am new to blackberry. I want to develop a countdown timer for a quiz type application that displays throughout the application on simulator. I am using storm version.'

how to implement it? if anybody answers i will be very thankful to them..

Answer (score 0):

You can use treads to maintain the timer to force it to redraw the screen after each passing second (use sleep and invalidate functions).

Comment: Hi Paullb thanks for your suggestion.As i am new to Blackberry i am not able to implement it can you explain me by taking sample...or give me any reference.

Thanks